# AS3: Instagram-like image (bitmap) filters?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image-processing

I'm wondering if there is some library (or maybe tutorial?) which can produce Instagram-like color tweaks for Bitmap/BitmapData objects in AS3.

ColorMatrix/ColorMatrixFilter will not be probably able to achieve such as results or yes?

[image: Instragram filters]

Comment: I was trying to make filters for Android. Could you post the 5x4 ColorMatrix filters in the answers if you have made progress with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed there is a great library ready made by [Eugene Zatepyakin](https://plus.google.com/100153080724550326314/posts) get it here https://github.com/inspirit/GPUImage

Also check [Adobe Pixel Bender Exchange](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?s=5&o=desc&pid=3662453&exc=26&event=productHome&from=1), there are lots of filters, you might be able find something there

Comment: While on android, it accepts ColorMatrix filters of 5x4 dimension, but the ones in the library are of 4x4,4x5 (varying sizes). Any suggestion on how to convert these? Or another link wihere I can find ColorMatrixFilters?

Answer (score 2):

You should give a look at [Pixel Bender](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/pixelbenderplugin/), it will be much easier to create photo filters than AS3. You can still use these filters with Flash using a Shader. There are some tutorials for basic filters on the Internet. When you're fluent with the PB syntax you will be able to create almost any filter you can imagine.

For example, I used Pixel Bender to do this: http://bit.ly/pgaOU3

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the right way. :) Don't you have some links to PB tutorials? Maybe I should start learning it. ;)

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/pixel_bender_basics.html Other useful resources here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html

Comment: Actually this won't work because Pixel bender's filters are working only thru Shader() class and that isn't supported on mobile devices. :/

Comment: Aw sorry... I guess a good way to simulate it would be using coloured layers with (or without) a gradient and a specific blendMode.

Comment: It's a bit harsh to unvalidate this answer since you didn't mention in your question it was for mobile purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Shader does work on mobile device,
use CPU render and not GPU when you publish the apk file